# Convert interface from another interface type

Tags: go, interface, casting, type-inference

I have a generic function used to set a target to a value extracted from a map. At the moment I have a large ugly switch statement for all the types the function supports but was wondering if there is any way to convert an interface based on the underlying type of another interface.

There is an added complication that the types of the two interfaces do not directly correlate. The target interface is a reference of the other interface (e.g. if target is *int, the other interface should be converted to an int). Don't worry about the examples that do not follow this pattern.

The following is the function I am using:

```
    if iface, isSet := config[name]; isSet {
        if convert != nil {
            var err error
            if iface, err = convert(iface); err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }

        var isType bool
        switch target := target.(type) {
        case *string:
            *target, isType = iface.(string)
        case *bool:
            *target, isType = iface.(bool)
        case *int:
            *target, isType = iface.(int)
        case **int:
            *target, isType = iface.(*int)
        case *[]string:
            *target, isType = iface.([]string)
        case *strslice.StrSlice:
            *target, isType = iface.([]string)
        case *map[string]string:
            *target, isType = iface.(map[string]string)
        case *map[string]struct{}:
            *target, isType = iface.(map[string]struct{})
        case *time.Duration:
            *target, isType = iface.(time.Duration)
        case *nat.PortSet:
            *target, isType = iface.(map[nat.Port]struct{})
        case **container.HealthConfig:
            *target, isType = iface.(*container.HealthConfig)
        default:
            return fmt.Errorf("target must be a reference")
        }
        if !isType {
            t := reflect.TypeOf(target).String()
            return fmt.Errorf("%s should be type %s", name, t[1:])
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: @Flimzy thank you for the note. I have updated the question to use the term convert rather than cast

Comment: @Flimzy The function does ["type assertion"](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) (different from type conversion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the reflect API:

```
// set sets the value pointed to target to value. 
func set(target interface{}, value interface{}) bool {
    t := reflect.ValueOf(target).Elem()
    v := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    if !v.Type().AssignableTo(t.Type()) {
        return false
    }
    t.Set(v)
    return true
}
```

Use the function like this in your code:

```
isType := set(target, iface)
```

Comment: Really good solution. Only suggestions are the line t.Set(t) should be t.Set(v) and I have added in my own code a check to see if either target or value are nil as this causes a panic

Comment: Note that while reflection allows for shorter code, it will be much _slower_.  That's okay for many use cases, but something to be aware of.